# How to Select multiple rows until columns reach a number limit

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm wondering, is how I would set up a query to select a table and select only a certain amount of rows until a columns value reached a specific number. I'll try to explain it better with code:

```
$get_armory = mysql_query("
SELECT * 
  FROM armory_owned 
 WHERE owner_id=$id 
   AND owned <= $mob_size 
 ORDER 
    BY attack");
```

So if Someone has 250 Mob size they can use that 250 mob size during an attack.

Example: They own 400 Daggers which has 2 Attack and 100 Swords with 5 attack. How would I setup the query to retrieve the best weapons as in 100 Swords and 150 daggers to equal to a total of 250 weapons?

Answer (score 0):

Used this:

```
$get_weapons = mysql_query("SELECT 
   O.player_id,
   O.item_id,
   O.attack,
   O.owned,
    (SELECT 
      sum(owned) FROM items_owned 
    WHERE owned <= O.owned AND player_id=$id) 'RunningTotal' 
FROM items_owned O
HAVING RunningTotal <= $mob_avail 
ORDER BY attack DESC");
```